# How to find next number to matched number from string of comma separated numbers using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string of comma separated numbers and I want to find out a next number of matched number so I am using this logic using covering string into `list`.

```
import json

s = '1,5,8,11,22,25'

def get_next(number):
    clean_s = f'[{s}]'
    number_list = json.loads(clean_s)
    input_number_index = number_list.index(number)
    return number_list[input_number_index + 1] # return next number

print(get_next(5)) # will print 8
print(get_next(11)) # will print 22
print(get_next(22)) # will print 25
print(get_next(1)) # will print 5
```

How will I solve this problem using [python regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

**Ex:**

```
import re

def get_next(number):
    m = re.search(r"(?<={},)(\d+),?".format(number), '1,5,8,11,22,25')
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    return "N\A"

print(get_next(5)) # will print 8
print(get_next(11)) # will print 22
print(get_next(22)) # will print 25
print(get_next(1)) # will print 5
print(get_next(25)) # will print N\A
```

Comment: Nice, but the lookahead is superfluous.

Comment: The comma was part of the lookahead and that, too, is superfluous. I think all you really need is `r"(?<={},)(\d+)"`. I don't know who downvoted you but I am offsetting that by upvoting you.